# How to compute direction between 2 locations

Tags: objective-c, mapping

Simmilar with [Direction between 2 Latitude/Longitude points in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042599/direction-between-2-latitude-longitude-points-in-c-sharp)

but with objective-c

Also I want a formula that works for large distance near the pole if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could save yourself a lot of time and use `CLLocation`'s `distanceFromLocation` method:

> distanceFromLocation:
>
> Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.
>
> Discussion
>   This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the following [complete but rather difficult stuff](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). A slightly easier description is found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Comment: Good answer (and good question). I voted up. Some jerks vote us down.