# C# calculate bearing from two GeoCoordinate

Tags: c#, geospatial, geo

I have two geo coordinates positions on the earth.

Using .NET I can easily calculate the distance:

```
GeoCoordinate a = new GeoCoordinate(50, 8);
GeoCoordinate b = new GeoCoordinate(34, -118);
double distanceInMeters = a.GetDistanceTo(b);
```

This uses the Haversine formula and execution is extremely fast.

How can i get the bearing using the same spherial model which the Haversine formula uses?

I would be happy with something like:

```
double bearing = HaversineBearingCalculator.calcBearingInDegrees(a, b);
```

or even

```
double bearing = a.GetBearingTo(b);
```

However .NET does not seem to offer anything like it.

Comment: Can't you define your own method that does exactly that? Like here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b035fff-7e0e-4ba2-acf4-8e4e022fbe7b/how-to-calculate-bearing-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: sorry, but your example works in a flat surface, I am talking about planet earth as a sphere here...

Comment: What do yout want? Orthodrome, loxodrome?

Comment: There is no absolute bearing over a sphere; your path would be of the  "Great Circle" and the only 2 absolute values is the initial and terminal bearings. All other bearings would need to be calculated by the current location on the path and the destination.

Comment: @user2088476 Sorry, maybe this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042599/direction-between-2-latitude-longitude-points-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't get why this question is upvoted. Issue is not related to coding, but to navigation understanding. And the question is impossible to solve

Comment: The last one gives 270 for your example. Is that correct?

Comment: One solution is to project your lat/long pairs to a equal-angle projection system. Then use simple planar calculation to find the bearing between x/y pairs