# Findout direction between two GIS points

Tags: c#, geometry, mapping, gis

I found the below link very helpful in calculating the bearing between 2 points. However I am looking for something to calculate if the points are going from East-West, West-East, North-South or South-North.
[Direction between 2 Latitude/Longitude points in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042599/direction-between-2-latitude-longitude-points-in-c-sharp/66482428#66482428)

Is there an easy way to find this out.
Appreciate any help..thank you

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to determine "rough" direction?

Comment: The direction between two point is the angle which is arcTan [(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)]

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out which "rough" direction the 2nd point is from the 1st point..like SE or NW etc..